# When trying to save a .jpg or .jpeg, Safari tries to force .dms extension onto end?

Tags: mac, safari, graphics

Not really the most pressing question, but it's bugged me enough to get an account and try my luck...

When I try to save any .jpg or .jpeg, Safari forces a .dms extension onto the end of it, and there's no other way to save that picture. Usually with most things like this, a solution is readily available if you Google for it, but I couldn't find an adequate answer. It's been like this for months. Sometimes it goes away, only to come back the next time I try to save a picture.

[image]

Comment: Please provide clear instructions on how to reproduce this issue. What version of Apple OS, Safari version, webpage URL and which image are you trying to save and by what method.

Comment: Same problem here.
Safari 9.1.3
OSX El Capitan (Version 10.11.6)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013) Go to http://globalstreetart.com/images/1mqsghx for example.
Press right click and save image. It now forces me to Use.dms.
The only Safari extension I have installed is the Adblock Plus 1.12.3 I'd love to know how to get rid of that stupid bug - otherwise I have to jump back to the Firefox eating SSD...

Answer (score -3):

use both then go to the file location and delete the .dms portion. Works for me.

Comment: This isn't a solution to stopping Safari from adding the .dms extension, which is what the OP is looking for.